# Populate a DropDownList with outside JS file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an outside JS file which contains an array

```
ListOfStudents = function(){
return ['Jane', 'Mark', 'Sarah'] }
```

And I need to add this array to a DropDownList in ASP.NET. Here is what I have, but it is not working. Your help would be appreciated.

```
 <script language="javascript" src="myJSFile.js"></script>

    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" onchange="javascript:ListOfStdents();" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Step 1: Learn how javascript and the DOM interact.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UpdatePanel, and have it populate at the server level. That being said, to do it in javascript, you'll need to do is create an option to be added to the item.

see: http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/06/06/add-items-in-drop-down-list-or-list-box-using-javascript/

Comment: Please do not encourage the copypasta.